# How to add a key into a derived schema?

Tags: inheritance, xsd, extend, derived, redefinition

Here is a simplified example of the problem:

`base.xsd`:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:element name="root" type="root" />
    <xs:complexType name="root">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="items" minOccurs="0" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:element name="items" type="items" />
    <xs:complexType name="items">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="item" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

`derived.xsd:`

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:redefine schemaLocation="base.xsd">
        <!-- redefining types from base.xsd ... -->
    </xs:redefine>
</xs:schema>
```

I would like to define a key on items in `derived.xsd`, but not in `base.xsd`. So the behavior of the base schema should not change, but in the derived schema, it should behave by the following definition:

```
<xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="items" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="item" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
                <xs:key name="itemKey">
                    <xs:selector xpath="item" />
                    <xs:field xpath="." />
                </xs:key>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Still, I `derived.xsd` should stay derived from `base.xsd`, because there are other elements in my real schema which I need to inherit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following worked for me.

`derived.xsd`

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:redefine schemaLocation="base.xsd">
        <xs:complexType name="root">
            <xs:complexContent>
                <xs:restriction base="root">
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="items" type="items" minOccurs="0">
                            <xs:key name="itemKey">
                                <xs:selector xpath="item" />
                                <xs:field xpath="." />
                            </xs:key>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:complexContent>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:redefine>
</xs:schema>
```